# Problem computing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}dx$ using contour integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to solve $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}\ dx$$ using a contour integral.

My Work:

Define a contour $C$ such that:[image]

Now we have $$\int_{C}\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}\ dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}\ dx+\int_{\text{Arc}}\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}\ dx$$
Now parametizing the integral over the arc: $$\int_{\text{Arc}}\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}\ dx=\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{0}^\pi \frac{\tan^{-1}(Re^{i\theta})}{Re^{i\theta}}iRe^{i\theta}\ d\theta=\lim_{R\to \infty} i\int_{0}^\pi \tan^{-1}(Re^{i\theta})\ d\theta=\frac{i\pi^2}{2}$$
We also note that the entire contour integral does not contain any poles, so it is $0$.

However this is where I run into a problem because that implies:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}\ dx=-\frac{i\pi^2}{2}$$
Which is obviously not true. If anyone can point out why my approach does not work or where I went wrong that would be great. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since $\tan^{-1}x = \frac{1}{2i}\log\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}$, it has two branch cuts ending at $x = \pm i$.

Comment: I see, but I'm not quite familiar with branch cuts. Would that fact be what is causing me to get the wrong answer?

Comment: It should be. In any event, the integral diverges logarithmically because $\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x} \approx \frac{\pi}{2|x|}$ as $|x| \to \infty$ along the real line.

Comment: @achillehui I see, thank you I just wanted to know if I was doing anything wrong with my contour integral.

Comment: @achillehui Isn't it technically a single branch cut that connects $i$ with $-i$ through the point at infinity?

Comment: @RandomVariable it is true that one can view it as a single branch cut
on the Riemann sphere.

Comment: If one really want to evaluate the integral using contour integral, one cam choose the branch cut to end at $i$ to $i\infty$ and wraps around it, saying using the contour: 
$$-R \to R \xrightarrow{\quad Re^{i\theta},\; \theta : 0 \to \pi/2\quad} iR+\epsilon\to i + \epsilon
\xrightarrow{
\quad i+\epsilon e^{i\theta},\; \theta : 0 \to -\pi\quad }
i - \epsilon\\
\to iR-\epsilon 
\xrightarrow{\quad Re^{i\theta}, \theta : \pi/2 \to \pi\quad} -R
$$

Comment: What is going on here? The integral obviously equals $+\infty.$

Comment: @zhw I know that it diverges I am just wondering why I get the wrong answer using a contour integral.

Comment: Integrate $-\frac{\log(1-iz)}{z}$ instead. When $z=x \in \mathbb{R}$, the imaginary part of $-\frac{\log(1-ix)}{z}$ is $\frac{\arctan x}{x}$. And $\frac{\log(1-iz)}{z}$ doesn't have a branch point in the upper half-plane, so you don't have to deform the contour.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thank you for your advice, all this talk about branch cuts is getting me a little confused haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, the complex function

$$ f(z) = \frac{\arctan z}{z} = \frac{1}{2iz}\ln\frac{1+iz}{1-iz} $$

has two branch points on $z=\pm i$ and a principal branch cut on $(-i\infty,-i)\cup (i,i\infty)$

Since your contour intersects the branch cut, the function is no loner analytic and the closed-loop integral does not equal $0$

Comment: I am not all too familiar with branch cuts, but is that what is represented on a Riemann Surface?

Comment: It's one representation, yes. Branch cuts are needed because many complex functions (like $\arg z$ or $\log z$) tend to be multi-valued, so in order to make them one-to-one, you'll have to define a "cut" on the complex plane to separate one "branch" from another. 

A real-function analogy would be something like $\arcsin x$, which only is defined only for outputs in $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ and "cuts off" everything else

Comment: I see that makes sense now